# update table through form

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

This is the next attempt I am making at solving this problem.  In my timeline is the prior attempt.

I have three tables **BOAT, BERTHAGE, LOCATION**.  These tables are joined in the following way in a query called **Boat_Move**

> BOAT(boat_ID) joins to BERTHAGE(boat)
>
> LOCATION(Loc_ID) joins to BERTHAGE(location)

This query is viewed on the form as a subform.

When the form opens up I will highlight the vessel which needs to have its location moved/updated

Once highlighted in the subform I click the edit button

```
Private Sub cmd_Edit_Click()
If Not (Me.Current_Week_Boat_Move.Form.Recordset.EOF And     Me.Current_Week_Boat_Move.Form.Recordset.BOF) Then
    With Me.Current_Week_Boat_Move.Form.Recordset
        Me.txt_Boat = .Fields("BOAT_NAME")
        Me.txt_Cur_Loc = .Fields("LOCATION")
        Me.txt_Cur_Flo = .Fields("FLOAT")
        Me.txt_Cur_Doc = .Fields("DOCK")
        Me.txt_Cur_Ori = .Fields("ORIENTATION")

        Me.cmd_Add.Caption = "Update"
        Me.cmd_Edit.Enabled = False

    End With
End If
End Sub
```

This puts the appropriate information into the text boxes.

I've also did up the following with the idea that this would update the **location(field)** in the **BERTHAGE(table)**

```
Private Sub cmd_Add_Click()

Dim strSQL As String

strSQL = "INSERT INTO BERTHAGE(BOAT, LOCATION)" & _
    " VALUES(" & Me.txt_Boat & ",'" & Me.txt_Cur_Loc & "');"

CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE BERTHAGE " & " SET LOCATION=" & Me.txt_Cur_Loc & _
    " WHERE LOCATION=" & Me.txt_Cur_Loc

Current_Week_Boat_Move.Form.Requery

cmd_Clear_Click

End Sub
```

I'm not sure if in this instance I should be creating a new table to make the update and then overwriting the older table.  The issue I see here is the older table is at around 24k records so that doesn't seem like the best way forward.

So at this point I'm facing two problems, and I am unsure if solving either one will solve the actual problem of updating the BERTHAGE(location) field.

View of the from 
[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Conventional approach would be main form bound to Boat and subform bound to Berthage with a combobox to select location. Find existing Boat record, change location in subform. Then all this INSERT and UPDATE actions are not needed. Do you care about history of boat locations and is that why you have junction table Berthage? If so, then should not edit existing record but add a new record. If you don't care about history, this junction table is likely not needed.

Comment: The problem is this information is used weekly on billing, so if I create a new record it will double up the billing for that week.  This is why I prefer to alter the existing record from say location 1 and move the boat to location 2, the owner of the vessel will only be billed for the one week.  Equally I don't want to create the need to reconcile each billing period, rather, run the report knowing all boats are only billed once per week.

Comment: So Berthage will have one record per week for each boat? My comment still applies. But if you don't want conventional approach, code you have should be possible. Is Location text or number field? UPDATE needs to identify which Berthage record to edit - boat, year, week.

Comment: Or locate by old berthage location - criteria using new location makes no sense.

Comment: Yes to the first question.  I think I see what you are saying about using the year & week to locate the record.  When I comment out the INSERT line the db then updates all prior records of the boat to the 'new' location (eg, they are all now location 2 regardless of where they were before) but the most current record does not change.  Location is a numbered field on both tables, on the location table it is Primary Key, on the Berthage table it is a linked number field.  I'm thinking I need an IF statement to tie the current record to the Update action?

Comment: An UPDATE action certainly needs proper filter criteria. If you set a compound index in table on boat/year/week fields, duplicate combination will not be allowed. Why do you not show year and week nor date value of any sort in INSERT action?

Comment: I thought it would pick the week & year up from the textboxes at the top of the form where it shows the week & year which comes directly from the BERTHAGE table.  I was trying this, no error, but also no result -         If BERTH_WEEK = DatePart("ww", Now()) And BERTH_YEAR = Year(Now()) Then
        
         DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE BERTHAGE " & " SET LOCATION=" & Me.txt_Cur_Loc & _
        " WHERE LOCATION = =" & BERTH_WEEK = DatePart("ww", Now()) And BERTH_YEAR = Year(Now())
        
        End If

Comment: INSERT only uses data you tell it to. Same is true for any SQL statement. So unless you have defaults set in table for year and week, those fields would not receive values. If you don't specify boat as well as year and week, all boats would be updated. Why do you show `==`? There is no parameter for location in WHERE clause and already advised using this criteria makes no sense.

Comment: Ok, I'll use your feed back and try to improve the situation. thanks